# how to make camera follow only in + x axis (forward only)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

base on this script i got in here..

public GameObject MyCamera; // The camera you want to follow the GameObject
    public GameObject ObjectToFollow; // What you want to follow

```
private Vector3 CameraPos ; // Variable that contains the Cameras x,y,z position

void Start()
{
    CameraPos = MyCamera.transform.position; // stores the Camera's position in the variable
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    CameraPos.x = ObjectToFollow.transform.position.x; // Change The X position on the camera variable to be the same as the ObjectToFollow X position
    MyCamera.transform.position = CameraPos; // Moves the Camera to the new position



}
```

this script make camera follow the player in the x axis (forward and backward)
how to change the code? to  make camera follow only for forward or + x axis?

Comment: I feel the question you are asking isn't in good faith with Stackoverflow role, in that the community is here to help you trouble shoot code etc you've created and have exhausted all attempts to solve a specific issue. This would appear to be more of "how to code" question / tutorial request.

Comment: I am sorry. I just starting to learn to code and unity 3d, and I am not so familiar in stackoverflow . thx for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if(MyCamera.transform.position.x < ObjectToFollow.transform.position.x){
        CameraPos.x = ObjectToFollow.transform.position.x;
        MyCamera.transform.position = CameraPos;
    }
}
```

This code will make your camera follow the character just for + x-axis. I also realised that you're using Update instead of LateUpdate. However, you should use LateUpdate for the camera updates. You can check the related [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html) about this.

Comment: @aldomuhammad glad that your problem is solved. If you found this answer helpful, you may consider picking it as the answer to the problem and upvote so that other people who might face similar issues will see this on top.